# Can't create alias using bash script

Tags: bash, alias

I want to create alias for nvim, so I tried:

```
alias nvim=$HOME/apps/neovim/nvim.appimage
alias nvim="$HOME/apps/neovim/nvim.appimage"
alias nvim='$HOME/apps/neovim/nvim.appimage'
eval "alias nvim='$HOME/apps/neovim/nvim.appimage'"
echo 'alias nvim="$HOME/apps/neovim/nvim.appimage"' >> ~/.bash_aliases
echo 'alias nvim="$HOME/apps/neovim/nvim.appimage"' >> ~/.bash_aliases && source ~/.bash_aliases
```

And it's work only if I type one of this commands by my hands, but if I place it to bash script and run it, their didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Please be specific.

Comment: Just put the commands to create the aliases in your shell script.  You could do `. ~/.bash_aliases` in your shell scripts.  It would be better to specify full path to `.bash_aliases` instead of using `~`.

Comment: @melpomene that's mean, after script execute, alias didn't created.

Comment: Show your script.

Comment: @melpomene https://gist.github.com/trigun117/e5f6fb1c2a6e1fe054fe04c763804387

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44382433/1848654

Comment: @melpomene link to another question almost solve my problem, but after script end, alias didn't save in system.